# Java how to disable JPanel components automatic vertical resizing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I've ran into a pretty annoying problem. The JPanel is adding a vertical gap between components, and I need to get rid of that. 
I'm trying to get this (Blue lines are the space I want to get rid of):

[image]

To look like this:

[image]

Here is my current class:

```
public class SummaryPanel extends JPanel
{
    private JLabel bagelLabel;
    private JLabel toppingLabel;
    private JLabel coffeeLabel;
    private JLabel shotsLabel;

    private JLabel subtotal;
    private JLabel tax;
    private JLabel total;

    private JPanel selectionsPanel;
    private JPanel totalPanel;

    public SummaryPanel()
    {
        bagelLabel = new JLabel("No bagel $0.00");
        toppingLabel = new JLabel("No topping $0.00");
        coffeeLabel = new JLabel("No coffee $0.00");
        shotsLabel = new JLabel("(Includes 0 shots) $0.00");

        subtotal = new JLabel("");
        tax = new JLabel("");
        total = new JLabel("");

        setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));

        selectionsPanel = new JPanel();

        selectionsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1));
        selectionsPanel.add(bagelLabel);
        selectionsPanel.add(toppingLabel);
        selectionsPanel.add(coffeeLabel );
        selectionsPanel.add(shotsLabel );

        totalPanel = new JPanel();
        totalPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
        totalPanel.add(subtotal);
        totalPanel.add(tax);
        totalPanel.add(total);

        totalPanel.setVisible(false);

        add(selectionsPanel);
        add(totalPanel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its controlled by the layout manager.

```
setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
```

You are using a GridLayout so each of the two components gets the same space.

```
    selectionsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1));
```

In turn each JLabel get a quarter of the total space available to each panel.

Instead you could use a BorderLayout:

```
//setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
setLayout(new BorderLayout);
```

Then when you add components to the panel you use:

```
add(selectionsPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
add(totalsPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

Now the preferred sizes will be respected.

Answer (score 1):

The `GridLayout` will divide the panel into the number of rows and columns specified, and each component will fill one of these cells in their entirety.

You may wish to consider using a [`BoxLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) instead.  This will allow you to stack your components without them expanding unpleasantly.